# I cannot import pandas as I keep getting a weird error

Tags: python, pandas, import, package

when I go to import panda from terminal or VS code studio I get the following error

```
    AttributeError: module 'calendar' has no attribute 'day_abbr'
```

the only code I've written is:

```
    import pandas as pd
```

is there a reason for this? how can I prevent this?

Comment: looks like it wasn't installed correctly, what distrubtion are you using? (homebrew, vanilla python ,anaconda, miniconda)?

Comment: I'm using anaconda

Comment: try opening the anaconda prompt (assuming your on windows) start > anaconda prompt > pip uninstall pandas then pip install pandas

Comment: I experienced this with a file named "calendar.py" in the same directory as my script. Renaming the file solved it